# How to determine the printing width of a type that can be formatted?

Tags: rust, formatting

If a type implements `Debug`, how do I determine the width of what would be printed from a `println!("{:?}", ...)` ?

```
fn width<T: std::fmt::Debug>(to_print_later: &T) -> usize {
    // what goes here?
}
```

Preferably without actually allocating anything on the heap and definitely without actually printing anything.

Comment: Why have people starting removing the language from the title of the question?  It is the most important piece of contextual information for the question.

Comment: [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/281829)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this without actually performing the formatting. Formatting is lazy by default and the formatting traits do not have a method that allows querying what the size would be.

Additionally, a type's implementation of `Debug::fmt` may or may not allocate, so it's impossible to say that *no* allocation will occur.

The simplest thing to do is create a string and return the length of the string:

```
fn width(to_print_later: &impl std::fmt::Debug) -> usize {
    format!("{:?}", to_print_later).len()
}
```

If you want to avoid your own allocation, you can write your own implementer of `fmt::Write` and format into it, only counting the length:

```
use std::fmt::{self, Write};

fn width(to_print_later: &impl fmt::Debug) -> usize {
    let mut c = CountingWriter::default();
    write!(&mut c, "{:?}", to_print_later).expect("Exceeded the usize");
    c.0
}

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct CountingWriter(usize);

impl fmt::Write for CountingWriter {
    fn write_str(&mut self, s: &str) -> fmt::Result {
        self.0 = usize::checked_add(self.0, s.len()).ok_or(fmt::Error)?;
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

This isn't a sure performance win, as it's possible that the implementation of `Debug::fmt` is the heavyweight part, not the allocation. As usual, profile to know what's best for your case.

---

Note that I use `Debug` in this answer, but it applies to the other traits like `Display` and `LowerHex` as well.

Comment: This looks like the most expedient solution, thanks.  But for the sake of pedantry, is it possible to make a custom type W implementing std::fmt::Write used in a std::fmt::Formatter's buffer , which would count instead of print or allocate?  I was actually expecting the answer to be that someone had already done this, if it was possible.

Comment: @DanielV reasonable enough. Added that and was more precise in my wording.

Comment: By "each formatting implementation" do you meant the specific implementation of Debug::fmt() on T or do you mean for things in the category of "{:?}" ?  I'm trying to look through the source code to see whether T::fmt() is called directly when {:?} is seen or whether an allocation is made an then fmt is called on that.

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own implementation of `std::fmt::Write` that counts instead of printing:

```rust
use std::fmt::Write;

#[derive(Default)]
struct Counter {
    count: usize,
}

impl Write for Counter {
    fn write_str(&mut self, s: &str) -> std::fmt::Result {
        self.count += s.len();
        Ok(())
    }

    fn write_char(&mut self, c: char) -> std::fmt::Result {
        self.count += c.len_utf8();
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut counter = Counter::default();
    write!(counter, "Number of {}: {}", "foo", 42).unwrap();

    println!("Count: {}", counter.count);
}
```

This won't allocate any big string, but will still allocate smaller strings for most of the parameters (because they are converted to a string before calling `write_str`).

Comment: Thanks.  By the last comment, are you saying that the library function that parses the "{:?}" will allocate rather than directly calling T::fmt ? (the formatting from the type in the original post).

Comment: Things like `"{:?}"` are parsed at compile time, but looking at the source, you'll see that for example to print an integer with padding, `write_char` will be called for the padding, but the integer itself will be converted to a string and `write_str` will be called. The string is hopefully reused so that few allocations will be needed.